# How RN implements multi-entry on multi-screen devices

Tags: react-native

I need to make an Android application on a hardware device. There are two screens on the hardware device, a main screen and a secondary screen. I hope that when the application starts, the two screens can load my different pages respectively. How should RN be implemented?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think you can package your app as a PWA (Progressive Web App) and load it in WebView on both devices.

Comment: I just use rn if I don't want to use webview, I hope to improve performance as much as possible